# GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain and aarch64

Tags: arm, embedded, gnu, arm64, toolchain

How can I compile a C code or an assembly code to AArch64 using the GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain,

I'd like to try some bare metal rPi 64 bit code.

I found Linaro Toolchain that seem's to do that but I guess the Arm Embedded Toolchain must be able to do that too.

Thanks

Comment: Was the answer useful ? If not, could you please briefly explain why ? thanks.

Comment: What happened with your awesome pulsar.webshaker.net? Can you please put it back online? :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use this [toolchain](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/7.2-2017.11/aarch64-elf/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_aarch64-elf.tar.xz) - the Arm Embedded Toolchain is for cortex-m/cortex-r microcontrollers, not for aarch64 cortex-a processors.
An excellent introduction to aarch64 on RPI3 would be to look at David Welch's excellent, ready to use bare-metal examples [here](https://github.com/dwelch67/raspberrypi) - more specifically at the Raspberry Pi 3 / Aarch64 [examples](https://github.com/dwelch67/raspberrypi/tree/master/boards/pi3).

Comment: Hi Frant. I finally used buildroot to compile a 64 bit raspberry pi linux. My question was how to use the ARM gnu toolchain provided by ARM and not the linaro one. But it seem's the ARM toolchain do not allow 64 bit compile. I do not know who down vote for your reply. It's not me. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hi Webshaker, thank you for your reply. I never ever thought you were the one who down voted the reply, I was just interested in your feedback. You just had mentioned willing to write some bare-metal on the RPI3, which usually means whithout any operating system such as Linux. In this case, the toolchain I pointed you to would have been the correct choice for directly running bare-metal aarch64 programs from  a 64  bits u-boot, or from a 32 bits one after having switched from aarch32 to aarch64.

Comment: Note that an additional  arm-eabi toolchain would have been required in this case for switching from aarch32 to aarch64 and transferring control to the aarch64  program.  David Welch's examples would have been very good for ramping-up on aarch64 programming in this case.